# Writing Regex pattern for HTML tags

Tags: regex

I'm very new to PHP writing and regular expressions. I need to write a Regex pattern that will allow me to "grab" the headlines in the following html tags:

<title>My news</title>
  <h1>News</h1>

<h2 class=\"yiv1801001177first\">This is my first headline</h2>                                                
<p>This is a summary of a fascinating article.</p>

<h2>This is another headline</h2>                                    
<p>This is a summary of a fascinating article.</p>

<h2>This is the third headline</h2>                                             
<p>This is a summary of a fascinating article.</p>

<h2>This is the last headline</h2>                        
<p>This is a summary of a fascinating article.</p>

So I need a pattern to match all the <h2> tags. This is my first attempt at writing a pattern, and I'm seriously struggling... 

/(<h+[2])>(.*?)\<\/h2>/  is what I've attempted. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can checkout the following similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454 which illustrates how to write regex expressions for parsing HTML.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A little hint: If you want to post code and/or HTML, paste it as-is into the edit box, then highlight it and press Ctrl-K. That way you don't have to mess around with HTML entities and escapes yourself, and it makes the code easier to read for us.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but in cases like this it's usually easier to use XML parser (which will automatically detect <h2> as well as <h2 class="whatever"> rather than regex, which you'll have to add a bunch of special cases to. Javascript, for example has XML DOM exactly for this purpose, I'd be surprised if PHP didn't have something similar.

Comment: Yes, I realize there are probably better ways to go about doing this, but this is for an assignment, and it specifically asked me to write a PHP script using Regex and then outputting it as an unordered list...

Comment: @Jo W, gently explain the person that imposed such requirement to this assignment to consult a doctor. Then use a HTML parser to solve the assignment. If you want to learn Regex, applying it to HTML would be the worst example of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it via regex is

```
#<h2\b[^>]*>(.*?)</h2>#is
```

This will match any `h2` tag and capture its contents in backreference `$1`. I've used `#` as a regex delimiter to avoid escaping the `/` later on in the regex, and the `is` options to make the regex case-insensitive and to allow newlines within the tag's contents.

There are circumstances where this regex will fail, though, as pointed out correctly by others in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have only checked in RegexBuddy, there following regex works:

```
<h2.*</h2>
```